# delete few lines below a pattern until a blank line is found using perl code

Tags: perl

I have a file in which i want to delete few lines after a pattern until a blank line is found below it and after that put a new line after the pattern using perl.
Here is the input file :

```
[NAMES]
Mark
Shaun

[MAIL_ADD]
douglas@mail.com
iamshaun@mail.com
mbirenk@mail.com
```

I want delete the description parts for each headers and put new description there. My perl code is as below and its only putting the new description below each header. I am not able to delete the older description:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
open(my $var, "<file.txt");
my @arr = <$var>;
my $cnt =0;
my $description1 = "Biren\nKumar\nStephen"
my $description2 = "rahul123@mail.com\nshael@mail.com"
while($cnt < @arr)
{
  my $cur_line = $arr[$cnt];
  if ($cur_line =~ s/\[NAMES\]/\[NAMES\]\n$description1/)
  {
    $arr[$cnt] = $cur_line;
  }
  elsif ($cur_line =~ s/\[MAIL_ADD\]/\[MAIL_ADD\]\n$description2/)
  {
    $arr[$cnt] = $cur_line;
  }
  $cnt++;
}
close($var);
open(my $var1, ">file.txt");
my $cnt1 =0;
while($cnt1 < @arr)
{
  print $var1 $arr[$cnt1];
  $cnt1++;
}
close $var1;
```

Please help me with this.. If you are not able to understand my question then please tell me, i'll try to clarify more.

my output file should look like below:

```
[NAMES]
Biren
Kumar
Stephen

[MAIL_ADD]
rahul123@mail.com
shael@mail.com
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to delete the entire line that has the description, or just the description? Maybe an example of what you expect on output would be useful.

Comment: ok..i am modifying my file content a bit, so that you can understand.

Comment: Can you put the expected output which will solve the problem easily ?

Comment: I think you have put 2 different files for the input you did not mention or match the respective output. Can you check once again ?

Comment: Okiee i have got your point . I have looked into you modified code !!

Comment: your provided code does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Since the substitution you are doing is depends on previous match, you can [slurp](http://perltricks.com/article/21/2013/4/21/Read-an-entire-file-into-a-string) the file and just change what is between HEADER1 and HEADER2:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.18;
my $old_file = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $description1 = "Biren\nKumar\nStephen";
my $description2 = "rahul123\@mail.com\nshael\@mail.com";
my $new_data = $old_file =~
    s/(.HEADER.*?\n).*?(\n.HEADER.*?\n).*/${1}${description1}${2}${description2}/msr;
say $new_data;

__DATA__
[HEADER1]
Mark
Shaun

[HEADER2]
douglas@mail.com
iamshaun@mail.com
mbirenk@mail.com
```

Here is the output:

```
[HEADER1]
Biren
Kumar
Stephen
[HEADER2]
rahul123@mail.com
shael@mail.com
```

I am also using a [non-destructive substitution](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/pod/perl5140delta.pod#Non-destructive_substitution) in case you need to keep your old values.

Here is how to do it with files if you need that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.18;
open(my $var, "<file.txt"); #open file to read
my $old_file = do { local $/; <$var> };
my $description1 = "Biren\nKumar\nStephen";
my $description2 = "rahul123\@mail.com\nshael\@mail.com";
my $new_data = $old_file =~
    s/(.HEADER.*?\n).*?(\n.HEADER.*?\n).*/${1}${description1}${2}${description2}/msr;
close $var;
open(my $var1, ">file.txt"); #open file to write
say $var1 $new_data;
```

The regex line is doing the following:

- (.HEADER.*?\n)  Store everything in the first HEADER line into $1
- .*?  match everything under the first header line (we are not going to store it or use it)
- (\n.HEADER.*?\n)  Store everything in the second HEADER line into $2
- ${1}${description1}${2}${description2}  Replace your input with the desired output
- /msr  multiline, single line can match \n and non-destructive replacement

[Link for docs on modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: Can you please explain me the below line:
    `my $new_data = $old_file =~
    s/(.HEADER.*?\n).*?(\n.HEADER.*?\n).*/${1}${description1}${2}${description2}/msr;
say $new_data;`

Comment: Sure, ill do it on the post.

Comment: You have used the '`HEADER`' to do your code... But if i have `NAMES` instead of `HEADER1` and `MAIL_ADD` instead of `HEADER2` ... Then how can i do it.

Comment: I have modified my code and my ques also.. There is no file named as set.sh.. By mistake i had put it there. My input and output file  is the same...file.txt...

Comment: Can't change the same file in memory like that, just create a new file and then rename it or overwrite if you wish.

Comment: In my code you can see i have opened my file for reading at first. then i store all the modifications to a local array. Then i close my file and again open it in write mode so that it opens a new file with same name(deletes the previous one). now i copy all my local array content to my file.txt...

Comment: Okay made a change so you can use the same file, but I don't recommend that since you can accidentally lose data if you don't have the close in the right place.

Comment: i have version 5.8.5.
i cant use v5.18. In v5.8.5 ..this error is comming.    `Bareword found where operator expected at put_lines_below.pl line 10, near "s/(.HEADER.*?\n).*?(\n.HEADER.*?\n).*/${1}${description1}${2}${description2}/msr"
syntax error at put_lines_below.pl line 10, near "s/(.HEADER.*?\n).*?(\n.HEADER.*?\n).*/${1}${description1}${2}${description2}/msr"
Execution of put_lines_below.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`

Answer (score 0):

In your assignment to `$description2`

```
my $description2 = "rahul123@mail.com\nshael@mail.com";
```

you have `@` which is intepolated. Since you have not defined an array named `@mail` the intepolation of `@mail` results in an empty string, hence, `$description2` will be

```
"rahul123.com\nshael.com
```

Furthermore, in your substitution line, you use the special characters `[]` that indicate character classes. You should escape them:

```
elsif ($cur_line =~ s/\[HEADER2\]/\[HEADER2\]\n$description2/)
```

instead of

```
elsif ($cur_line =~ s/[HEADER2]/[HEADER2]\n$description2/)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information... :) 
I'll rectify my code. But still now i am not able to get my output.. Can you please help me on that

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps..

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

push @ARGV, 'file.txt';

my %dump;
my $header;

while (<>) {
  if (/^\[([^\]]+)\]$/) {
    $header = $1;
    $dump{$header} = "";
    next;
  }
  $dump{$header} .= $_ if $header;
}

# ==== here do the change ===
$dump{"NAMES"} = <<EOL;
Biren
Kumar
Stephen
EOL

$dump{"MAIL_ADD"} = <<EOL;
rahul123@mail.com
shael@mail.com
EOL
# ===========================

# now print it back to <STDOUT>
foreach (sort keys %dump) {
  chomp($dump{$_});
  print "[$_]\n$dump{$_}\n\n";
}
```